# There is a $C > 0$ such that $\vert f(z)-f(w)\vert \leq C\vert z-w\vert$ for a holomorphic map into $B(0, R)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $0<\delta<r$ and $R>0$, and $a\in\mathbb C$. I want to show that there exists $C>0$ such that for all holomorphic functions $f\colon B(a,r)\to B(0,R)$, we have
$$
\vert f(z)-f(w)\vert\leq C\vert z-w\vert
$$
for $z,w\in B(a,\delta)$.

I'm not sure how to approach this. I was wondering if I could use that
$$
\left\vert\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}\right\vert\leq\frac{\Vert f\Vert_{C(a,\rho)}}{\rho^n}
$$
for some $0<\rho<r$. I also have an expression from biholomorphic maps from $B(0,1)$ to itself, but I'm not sure if I could use that here. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\rho = (r - \delta)/2$. Then for any $z \in B(a, \delta)$ the closure of the disk $B(z, \rho)$ is contained in $B(a, r)$, so that Cauchy's estimate for the derivate gives
$$
 |f'(z)| \le \frac{\Vert f \Vert_{C(a,\rho)}}{\rho} \le \frac{2R}{r - \delta} =: C
 \, .
$$
This $C$ satisfies the desired inequality: Let $\gamma(t) = z + t (w-z)$, $0 \le t \le 1$, be the straight path from $z$ to $w$. Then
$$
f(z) - f(w) = \int_\gamma f'(\zeta) \, d\zeta = (w-z)\int_0^1 f'(z + t(w-z)) \, dt
$$
and therefore
$$
|f(z) - f(w)| \le |z-w| \int_0^1 |f'(z + t(w-z))| \, dt \le C |z-w| \, .
$$

Comment: Right, so the idea is to make this uniform bound on the derivative for each $z\in B(a,\delta)$. I'm assuming then that we have
$$
\frac{\vert f(z)-f(w)\vert}{\vert z-w\vert}=\vert f'(\zeta)\vert
$$
for some $\zeta$? Or how would you relate the difference quotient (in absolute value) uniformly to a derivative?

Comment: @ShaVuklia: No, the mean-value theorem from the real numbers does not hold in two or more dimensions. But you have an upper estimate of the difference quotient in terms of the maximum of the derivate. See updated answer.

Comment: Oh, of course. I actually learned that a couple of years ago, but haven't used it ever since. Well, there is a first time for everything:) Won't forget it anymore. Thanks!